# ¿Cómo mejorar la responsividad de una sección de sitio web?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsivo

Tengo un menú en un sitio web que no logro hacer que se vea responsivo en distintas pantallas, en la PC se ve bien, pero a la hora de verlo en un celular, se sale del contenedor.

Así se ve en la PC:

[image: Así se ve en la PC]

Así en Iphone 12 pro. Se sale del contenedor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y así en Samsung S8+. Se sale aún peor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté modificando los valores de width y padding pero sigue sin ajustarse a cada pantalla de celular, o incluso una de las esferas se va para abajo. Este es el código, lo coloqué con la opción HTML de Elementor en una plantilla de WordPress:

```html
 <style>
    
    #colorNav li.cn{        background-color:white;color:#1f419d;}
    
    #colorNav > ul{
        width: 450px; 
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    
    #colorNav > ul > li{ /* will style only the top level li */
        list-style: none;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2) inset,1px 1px 1px #CCC;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 1;
        margin: 1px;
        border-radius: 53px;
        position:relative;
    }
    
    #colorNav > ul > li > a{
        color:inherit;
        text-decoration:none !important;
        font-size: 28px;
        padding: 28px;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul{
        position:absolute;
        list-style:none;
        text-align:center;
        width:180px;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-90px;
        font:bold 12px 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
        
        max-height:0px;
        overflow:hidden;
        
        -webkit-transition:max-height 0.4s linear;
        -moz-transition:max-height 0.4s linear;
        transition:max-height 0.4s linear;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li{
        background-color:#313131;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li a{
        padding:12px;
        color:#fff !important;
        text-decoration:none !important;
        display:block;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li:nth-child(odd){ 
        background-color:#363636;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li:hover{
        background-color:#444;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li:first-child{
        border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
        margin-top:25px;
        position:relative;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li:first-child:before{ /* the pointer tip */
        content:'';
        position:absolute;
        width:1px;
        height:1px;
        border:5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom-color:#313131;
        left:50%;
        top:-10px;
        margin-left:-5px;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li:last-child{
        border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
    }
    
    #colorNav li:hover ul{
        max-height:200px; /* Increase when adding more dropdown items */
    }
    #colorNav li ul {
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    #colorNav li:hover ul {
        z-index: 1337;
    }
    
    
    
    </style>
            <nav id="colorNav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="cn">
                        <a href="#" class="fa-solid fa-key"></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Sistema</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Webmail</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Instructivo alta - Sistema de Gestión Notarios</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="cn">
                        <a href="#" class="fa-solid fa-search"></a>
                    
                    </li>
                    <li class="cn">
                        <a href="#" class="fa-solid fa-link"></a>
                        
                    </li>
                    <li class="cn">
                        <a href="#" class="fa-solid fa-file-arrow-down"></a>
                    
                    </li>
                    <li class="cn">
                        <a href="#" class="fa-solid fa-user-tie"></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu etiqueta ul tiene un padding-left que molesta, además el with debería ser  max-content

```
#colorNav > ul {
    width: max-content;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<style>
    
    #colorNav li.cn{        background-color:white;color:#1f419d;}
    
   #colorNav > ul {
    width: max-content;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0;
    }
    #colorNav > ul > li{ /* will style only the top level li */
        list-style: none;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2) inset,1px 1px 1px #CCC;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 1;
        margin: 1px;
        border-radius: 53px;
        position:relative;
    }
    
    #colorNav > ul > li > a{
        color:inherit;
        text-decoration:none !important;
        font-size: 28px;
        padding: 28px;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul{
        position:absolute;
        list-style:none;
        text-align:center;
        width:180px;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-90px;
        font:bold 12px 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
        
        max-height:0px;
        overflow:hidden;
        
        -webkit-transition:max-height 0.4s linear;
        -moz-transition:max-height 0.4s linear;
        transition:max-height 0.4s linear;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li{
        background-color:#313131;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li a{
        padding:12px;
        color:#fff !important;
        text-decoration:none !important;
        display:block;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li:nth-child(odd){ 
        background-color:#363636;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li:hover{
        background-color:#444;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li:first-child{
        border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
        margin-top:25px;
        position:relative;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li:first-child:before{ /* the pointer tip */
        content:'';
        position:absolute;
        width:1px;
        height:1px;
        border:5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom-color:#313131;
        left:50%;
        top:-10px;
        margin-left:-5px;
    }
    
    #colorNav li ul li:last-child{
        border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
    }
    
    #colorNav li:hover ul{
        max-height:200px; /* Increase when adding more dropdown items */
    }
    #colorNav li ul {
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    #colorNav li:hover ul {
        z-index: 1337;
    }
    
    
    
    </style>
            <nav id="colorNav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="cn">
                        <a href="#" class="fa-solid fa-key"></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Sistema</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Webmail</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Instructivo alta - Sistema de Gestión Notarios</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="cn">
                        <a href="#" class="fa-solid fa-search"></a>
                    
                    </li>
                    <li class="cn">
                        <a href="#" class="fa-solid fa-link"></a>
                        
                    </li>
                    <li class="cn">
                        <a href="#" class="fa-solid fa-file-arrow-down"></a>
                    
                    </li>
                    <li class="cn">
                        <a href="#" class="fa-solid fa-user-tie"></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```